# Validate Date String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

We have a new field being added to our app where the client wants to be able to put in `Sept 22`. The input will be part of an import with 100 or so records. I know there are many libraries for parsing it but we want to be able to validate it. In case someone were to make a typo. Any thoughts or libraries to do this?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Please select an answer if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.parse will parse "Sept 22" with current year.
you can just make a dateTime with specified year as

```
date = DateTime.parse("Sept 22")
date_time_with_year = DateTime.new(year, date.month, date.day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)

You can do things like

```
Chronic.parse('may 27th', :now => Time.local(2000, 1, 1))
#=> Sat May 27 12:00:00 PDT 2000
```

It will attempt to guess what the string was trying to convey, by default (ie: `"Sept 27"` will actually parse to something like `2013-09-27 12:00:00 -0500`